# Composite 2 UIImageViews using Core Image, when one ImageView is in a ScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView` inside it. The user can pan and zoom the image inside the scrollView.

I also have a `UIImageView` in the main view (above the scrollView), and the user can move that image around the screen.

I'm using CISourceOverCompositing to combine them both:

```
-(UIImage *) compositeFinalImage {

    CIImage *foregroundImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:foregroundImageView.image.CGImage];

    CIFilter *composite =[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
    [composite setValue: foregroundImage forKey: @"inputImage"];
    [composite setValue: [CIImage imageWithCGImage:backgroundImage.CGImage] forKey: @"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *finalImage = [composite valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:finalImage fromRect:finalImage.extent] scale:1.0 orientation:userImageOrientation];    
}
```

...but the location and scale of the image has been lost when I make it a `CIImage` and the foreground image is always at the bottom left.

So I tried to use `imageByApplyingTransform` to move the position of the foreground image (and eventually I will have to apply scale transform as well), but I get the position from the ImageView, but the coordinates need to be in the native resolution of the background image itself... but the background image is moving around (which I guess means I have to take the `ContentOffset` into account somehow), and the background image has a certain scale, and the foreground image has a certain scale...

It seems weird that it's needed to re-produce all of the transformation with regards to different scale, rotation and position variables of each image...

This is the basic idea of what I'm trying to do (the left side is in the main view coordinates, while the right side is in native image coordinates).

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

[image: the overall plan]